# How to Parse Bluetooth Beacons in xamarin.ios?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bluetooth, xamarin.ios, beacon

I'm trying to recognize Eddystone beacons with an iPhone and Xamarin.Forms, so I chose this NuGet package to do this: https://github.com/andijakl/universal-beacon/

In Android it works well and recognizes every type of beacon, included Eddystone ones. With iOS, beacons are recognized but I'm not able to get their type and id. I saw that in the library there is a `CocoaBluetoothCentralDelegate` class that doesn't parse the information completely.

I'm partially sure that there is something with that commented code but I'm haven't worked out how to extract the information I need from `advertisementData`.

Thanks to all that will answer me! I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54293722/7089089), but it is not complete and it doesn't help me:

```
internal class CocoaBluetoothCentralDelegate : CBCentralManagerDelegate
{
    public event EventHandler<BLEAdvertisementPacketArgs> OnAdvertisementPacketReceived;

    #region CBCentralManagerDelegate

    public override void ConnectedPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"ConnectedPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral {peripheral})");
    }

    public override void DisconnectedPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral, NSError error)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"DisconnectedPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral {peripheral}, NSError {error})");
    }

    public override void DiscoveredPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral, NSDictionary advertisementData, NSNumber RSSI)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Cocoa peripheral {peripheral}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Cocoa advertisementData {advertisementData}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Cocoa RSSI {RSSI}");

        var bLEAdvertisementPacket = new BLEAdvertisementPacket()
        {
            Advertisement = new BLEAdvertisement()
            {
                LocalName = peripheral.Name,
                ServiceUuids = new List<Guid>(),
                DataSections = new List<BLEAdvertisementDataSection>(),
                ManufacturerData = new List<BLEManufacturerData>()
            },
            AdvertisementType = BLEAdvertisementType.ScanResponse,
            BluetoothAddress = (ulong)peripheral.Identifier.GetHashCode(),
            RawSignalStrengthInDBm = RSSI.Int16Value,
            Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now
        };

        //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdataserviceuuidskey
        //if (advertisementData.ContainsKey(CBAdvertisement.DataServiceUUIDsKey))
        //{
        //    bLEAdvertisementPacket.Advertisement.ServiceUuids.Add(
        //        item: new BLEManufacturerData(packetType: BLEPacketType.UUID16List,
        //                                      data: (advertisementData[CBAdvertisement.DataServiceUUIDsKey])));
        //}

        //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdataservicedatakey
        //if (advertisementData.ContainsKey(CBAdvertisement.DataServiceDataKey))
        //{
        //    bLEAdvertisementPacket.Advertisement.DataSections.Add(
        //        item: new BLEManufacturerData(packetType: BLEPacketType.ServiceData,
        //                                      data: advertisementData[CBAdvertisement.DataServiceDataKey]));
        //}

        //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdatamanufacturerdatakey
        if (advertisementData.ContainsKey(CBAdvertisement.DataManufacturerDataKey))
        {
            bLEAdvertisementPacket.Advertisement.ManufacturerData.Add(
                item: new BLEManufacturerData(packetType: BLEPacketType.ManufacturerData,
                                              data: (advertisementData[CBAdvertisement.DataManufacturerDataKey]
                                                     as NSData).ToArray()));
        }

        // Missing CBAdvertisement.DataTxPowerLevelKey

        var bLEAdvertisementPacketArgs = new BLEAdvertisementPacketArgs(data: bLEAdvertisementPacket);
        OnAdvertisementPacketReceived?.Invoke(this, bLEAdvertisementPacketArgs);
    }

    public override void FailedToConnectPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral peripheral, NSError error)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"FailedToConnectPeripheral(CBCentralManager central, CBPeripheral {peripheral}, NSError {error})");
    }

    public override void UpdatedState(CBCentralManager central)
    {
        switch (central.State)
        {
            case CBCentralManagerState.Unknown:
                Debug.WriteLine("CBCentralManagerState.Unknown");
                break;
            case CBCentralManagerState.Resetting:
                Debug.WriteLine("CBCentralManagerState.Resetting");
                break;
            case CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported:
                Debug.WriteLine("CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported");
                break;
            case CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized:
                Debug.WriteLine("CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized");
                break;
            case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff:
                Debug.WriteLine("CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff");
                break;
            case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn:
                Debug.WriteLine("CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn");
                central.ScanForPeripherals(peripheralUuids: new CBUUID[] { },
                                                           options: new PeripheralScanningOptions { AllowDuplicatesKey = true });
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public override void WillRestoreState(CBCentralManager central, NSDictionary dict)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"WillRestoreState(CBCentralManager central, NSDictionary {dict})");
    }

    #endregion CBCentralManagerDelegate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the other answer you linked:

> > The universal beacon library does not have an iOS implementation that converts the iOS packets to the universal packets. This need to be implemented.

In your code above, you are showing a possible implementation of this.  There may be a number of problems the implementation shown, but I can see a big one right away:

The implementation shown uses iOS CoreBluetooth callback to read the beacon packet data.  One big problem with this:  **iBeacon detections cannot work with the code shown.  On iOS, the operating system is designed to block detections of iBeacon packets using the CoreBluetooth APIs.  You have to use the CoreLocation APIs, which the implementation shown does not do.**

It is in theory possible to use the CoreBluetooth callback shown to parse Eddystone beacon packets and AltBeacon packets (which are manufacturer advertisements delivered on iOS when the app is in the foreground only.)  But it does not sound to me like this code is anywhere close to being ready to go.

It sounds to me like you are on the bleeding edge trying to get this working here.  You probably need somebody with solid iOS native programming skills (and CoreBluetooth/CoreLocation development skills) to get this working.

Comment: I managed to parse Eddystone beacon packtes and now i'm able to recognize them, but  i miss one point. Like you said the advertisements arrive on ios only when app is in foreground. Is there any way to get this working in background mode using coreBluetooth?

Comment: The key to getting Eddystone scanning working in the background is to set up the scan to specify the Eddystone service UUID on the scan.  Unfiltered scans on iOS return no results in the background.  This will work OK if you only care about detecting Eddystone. But obviously filtering for Eddystone only will break detections of other kinds of beacons.